# How to change aspect ratio in unity game view window depending on scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, orientation

Currently I am creating a game for iOS. I would like that some scenes of my game have aspect ratios that correspond with an iPhone's portrait orientation while others have aspect ratios that correspond with an iPhone's landscape orientation and therefore I am wondering how I can change between the aspect rations iPhone 5 tall (9:16) and iPhone 5 wide (16:9) depending on the scene I am in.

Comment: Change the viewport size and the view matrix.

Comment: please explain how in an answer @Gusman

Comment: How? Reading the documentation and learning how to do it.

Comment: yes but that way i cannot accept your answer...but if you don't care about getting your answer accepted...@Gusman

Comment: I don't care...

Comment: k thanks then i guess...@Gusman

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think it can help you:
[Screen Orientation](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1107629/i-want-to-change-default-screen-orientation-for-on.html)